# On definition and usefulness of "Cayley table"

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, definition, cayley-table

Dummit-foote p.21

> Let $G=\{g_1,\cdots,g_n\}$ be a finite group with $g_1=1$.
>
> The Cayley table of $G$ is the $n\times n$ matrix whose (i,j)-entry is $g_ig_j$.

This definition is based on an **order** of $G$.

If one gives another order on $G$, then the Cayley table of $G$ would not be identical to the original.

> Q: Is there any way to make the concept of Cayley table precise?

This table is useful to visualize **small**(informally speaking) finite groups.

However, using this table to study them is just the same thing as using **geometry** in topology or analysis.

What are your thoughts?

Comment: The definition *is* precise. The Cayley table requires choosing an order for the elements of the group. Different orders will give different tables. Some orderings highlight some properties of the group, typically subgroups. Studying "unordered Cayley tables" would probably be equivalent to studying the group as a whole.

Comment: The "coordinate-free" version of a Cayley table is just the group operation $G\times G \to G$ itself.